# What is the volume of the prism? (Vectors)

Tags: vectors

Given, triangle vertices: $A = (0,0,1),\, B = (1,1,1),\, C = (1,2,3)$

Consider the prism having the triangle $ABC$ as the base and as the roof, which is obtained by translating the triangle $ABC$ by the vector $v = (1, 1, 1)$

So what I did was use the Triple Scalar Product, but cut in half (since it's a triangle base/roof).

So,

$$\text{Volume} = \frac{1}{2}\left\lvert v\cdot\left(\vec{AB} \times \vec{AC}\right)\right\rvert$$

I get:

$$\begin{array}{cl} \left\lvert v\cdot\left(\vec{AB} \times \vec{AC}\right)\right\rvert &= 1((2\times 1)-(2\times0)) - 1((2\times1)-(1\times0)) + ((2\times1)-(1\times1)) \\
&= 2-2+1 \\
&= 1
\end{array}$$

and finally:

$$\text{Volume} = \frac{1}{2}$$

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your calculations are correct. It would be good for the reader or the person who is correcting this, to calculate the cross product first, so that the expressions do not become too "crowded". Also, look up some tips on how to write in MathJax - LaTeX in this site :).